# Increasing the database session duration with Symfony

Tags: symfony, session

My session for Symfony is being placed into the database as intended, however the issue is that the session lifetime is only 24 minutes. I'm attempting to increase this but it doesn't seem to be working.

My framework.yaml file:

```
session:
    enabled: true
    handler_id: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
    cookie_secure: 'auto'
    cookie_samesite: 'lax'
    cookie_lifetime: 604800
```

My services.yaml file:

```
services:
    Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler:
        arguments:
            - '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
```

My security.yaml file:

```
firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            login_throttling:
                limiter: app.custom.limiter
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            switch_user: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: logout
                # where to redirect after logout
                # target: app_any_route
            remember_me:
                secret:   ‘%kernel.secret%’
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you know it's only 24 minutes?

Comment: Because I look at the database entry and it shows session_lifetime that goes 24 minutes after the session starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `gc_maxlifetime` in PHP is `1440` which explains the 24 minutes.

So update your [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) value.